# vue router-view does not work if wrapped in a component

Tags: vue.js

**UPDATE:**

### **It magically starts to work later on after I clear browser cache, I do not know what happened before.**

---

I wonder how to include router-view in a component rather than directly use it?

For Example:

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import router from "./router"
import App from './App.vue'


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App),
  router
})
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <page-content></page-content>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import pageContent from "./page-content.vue";

  export default {
    name: 'app',
    data() { return {}; },
    components: {
      "page-content": pageContent
    }
  }
</script>
```

**page-content.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="page-content">
        <router-view>
        </router-view>      
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
    }
</script>
```

**router.js**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
Vue.use(VueRouter);

const Foo = { template: '<div>foo</div>' }
const Bar = { template: '<div>bar</div>' }

const routes = [{ path: '/', component: Foo }]

export default new VueRouter({
  routes
})
```

The problem is I can not see **foo** shown up on page

Comment: check [Vue Router: nested route](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html), also it encloses one example at the end of the guide.

Comment: I just saw you added `router.js`. You need to change it like `const routes = [{ path: '/', component: PageContent, children: [{ path: '', component: Foo}]}]`

Comment: @Sphinx Thanks, it works, but one quick question, for the top level `path:"/"`, how does the router know where to put the Foo component(and why it needs to put Foo there)? Since the router-view is for the children config part

Comment: check the last example in the user guide of first comment, then look into this (keyword: **empty subroute path**):  `At this point, with the above configuration, when you visit /user/foo, nothing will be rendered inside User's outlet, because no sub route is matched. Maybe you do want to render something there. In such case you can provide an empty subroute path`

Comment: @Sphinx Thanks, in that example, there is router-view in top level component(**app**), but in my example, only the page-content component has router-view, I was wondering How vue-router knows it should put Foo in page-content?

Comment: lol, i just saw that in your `app.vue`... but look into this [vue router fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L7hscd8h/14197/), if remove `<rounter-view>` of direct child of `#app`, it will not work.